# Moment js getting time ago

Tags: momentjs

I'm using moment to get time ago, but for things that happened 1 hour ago, it puts it like this: 'am hour ago', is it possible to get '1 hour ago'? Same thing for months, 'a  month ago' => '1 month ago'

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure moment to display relative times in any format you desire. For example:

```js
moment.updateLocale('en', {
    relativeTime : {
        future: "in %s",
        past:   "%s ago",
        s  : 'a few seconds',
        ss : '%d seconds',
        m:  "a minute",
        mm: "%d minutes",
        h:  "1 hour ago", //this is the setting that you need to change
        hh: "%d hours",
        d:  "a day",
        dd: "%d days",
        w:  "a week",
        ww: "%d weeks",
        M:  "1 month ago", //change this for month
        MM: "%d months",
        y:  "a year",
        yy: "%d years"
    }
});
```

After this change has been made the moment library can be used as usual.

Following are some examples:

```js
moment('2021-07-23 14:00:00').fromNow();
```

If you have the date coming in a different format than expected then you also need to provide the format in which you are getting it. Not doing so will return 'Invalid date'.

```js
moment('21/07/2021',"DD/MM/YYYY").fromNow();
```

You can also specify multiple formats:

```js
moment('21-07-2021', ['DD/MM/YYYY', 'YYYY/MM/DD']).fromNow();
```

You can always check whether you got a valid date or not. This helps put some checks in place or can be helpful when debugging code:

```js
moment('abc', ['MM/DD/YYYY', 'YYYY/MM/DD']).isValid() //false
```

For more information see the docs here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/relative-time/

Comment: How do I pass the date after this, I'm getting an error when doing: ****moment.updateLocale('en', {
        s  : 'A Few Seconds Ago',
        m:  "1 Minute Ago",
        h:  "1 Hour Ago", //this is the setting that you need to change
        d:  "1 Day Ago",
        w:  "1 Week Ago",
        M:  "1 Month Ago", //change this for month
        y:  "1 Year Ago",
})(date).fromNow(false)

Comment: I have edited the answer and included some examples.

Comment: So I update moment when the page is loaded, and then I just use it normally.

Answer (score 0):

{moment(new Date(your date).getTime()).fromNow()}